# How to show $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+} \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin x}{x + t}dx = \dfrac{\pi}{2}$?

Tags: convergence-divergence, improper-integrals

It is well-known that
$$
    \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin x}{x}dx = \dfrac{\pi}{2}
$$
Let
$$
     f(t) = \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin x}{x + t}dx \ \forall t > 0
$$
I want to know if
$$
     \lim_{t \downarrow 0} f(t) = \dfrac{\pi}{2}
$$

From [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+of+sin%28x%29%2F%28x+%2B+t%29dx+from+0+to+inf), [this is indeed true](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=lim+Ci%28t%29+sin%28t%29+%2B+1%2F2+cos%28t%29+%28%CF%80+-+2+Si%28t%29%29+as+t+tends+to+0). However, the answer it gives is via the cosine integral function and sine integral function. I wonder if whether we can show this solely by convergence theorem. I tried to bound the integrand by $\left\vert \dfrac{\sin x}{x} \right\vert$ but this is not Riemann integrable on $(0, \infty)$. Any hints would be appreciated, thank you

Comment: Hint. Consider the limit of the difference $\lim_{t \downarrow 0} t\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin x}{x(x + t)}dx$. The integral on the right of the infinitesimal $t$ is convergent (why?)

Comment: @RobertZ What you meant is consider this integral ?  $$ \int_0^\infty \left(\dfrac{\sin x}{x(x + t)} - \dfrac{\sin x}{x + t}\right) dx $$

Comment: You can integrate once by parts: $$
f(t) = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{1 - \cos x}}{{(x + t)^2 }}{\rm d}x} .
$$

Comment: I mean that if you show that  $\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin x}{x(x + t)}dx$ is bounded then $\lim_{t \downarrow 0} \int^\infty_0 \frac{\sin x}{x}-f(t)\mathrm{d}x=\lim_{t \downarrow 0} t\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin x}{x(x + t)}dx=0$

Comment: @ThànhNguyễn Robert Z meant that you consider the difference $f(t)-\int^{+\infty}_0 \frac{\sin x}{x}\mathrm{d}x$.

Comment: @RobertZ Ok, I need another hint to prove $\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin x}{x(x + t)}dx$. I split the integral into two: $$ \int_0^1 \dfrac{\sin x}{x(x + t)}dx + \int_1^\infty \dfrac{\sin x}{x(x + t)}dx $$ The second integral is bounded by $\dfrac{\ln(1 + t)}{t} \rightarrow 1$ as $t \rightarrow 0^+$, but the first integral is bounded by $\ln\left(\dfrac{t+1}{t}\right)$, which is unbounded as $t \rightarrow 0^+$

Comment: @RobertZ nvm, I got it. Forget the term t. Thank you for your hints

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the full answer based on @RobertZ's comment. We have
$$
      \begin{align*}
           \left\vert f(t) - \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin x}{x}dx \right\vert &= \left\vert t\int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin x}{x(x + t)}dx \right\vert\\
           &\le t \int_0^1 \left\vert \dfrac{\sin x}{x} \right\vert \dfrac{1}{x  + t}dx + t \int_1^\infty \vert \sin x \vert \dfrac{1}{x(x + t)}dx\\
           &\le t \int_0^1 \dfrac{dx}{x + t} + t \int_1^\infty \dfrac{dx}{x(x+t)}\\
&= t \ln\left(\dfrac{t + 1}{t}\right) + \ln(1 + t) \xrightarrow{t \downarrow 0} 0
      \end{align*}
$$
Therefore,
$$
     \lim_{t \downarrow 0} \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin x}{x + t}dx = \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin x}{x}dx = \dfrac{\pi}{2} \hspace{0.5cm}\blacksquare
$$

Comment: Note the second term $\displaystyle t \int_1^\infty \dfrac{dx}{x(x+t)}\le t \int_1^\infty\frac{1}{x^2}dx\to0$

Answer (score 2):

Observe that

$$f(t)=\int_{t}^\infty\frac{\sin(x-t)}{x}~\mathrm{d}x=\cos t\int_{t}^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}~\mathrm{d}x-\sin t\int_t^\infty\frac{\cos x}{x}~\mathrm{d}x.$$

(this is justified as the second integral converges for $t>0$). Now

$$\lim_{t\downarrow0}\int_t^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}~\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}~\mathrm{d}x$$

(this can easily be justified by splitting the integral at $1$ and applying the DCT for example), and furthermore

$$\left\lvert\sin t\int_t^1\frac{\cos x}{x}~\mathrm{d}x\right\rvert\leq\lvert\sin t\rvert\int_t^1\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x}=\left\lvert\sin t\ln t\right\rvert\to0$$

as $t\downarrow 0$, so that

$$\sin t\int_t^\infty\frac{\cos x}{x}~\mathrm{d}x=\sin t\int_t^1\frac{\cos x}{x}~\mathrm{d}x+\sin t\int_1^\infty\frac{\cos x}{x}~\mathrm{d}x\to0$$

as $t\downarrow0$. It follows that

$$\lim_{t\downarrow0}f(t)=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}~\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go beyond the limit
$$f(t) = \int_0^\infty \dfrac{\sin (x)}{x + t}\,dx=\text{Ci}(t) \sin (t)+\frac{1}{2} (\pi -2 \text{Si}(t)) \cos (t) $$ where appear the sine and cosine integral functions.

Expanded as a series around $t=0$
$$f(t)=\frac{\pi }{2}+ (\log (t)+\gamma -1)\,t+O\left(t^2\right)$$